# Can we show $\{z∈ℂ^2:\|z\|=1\}=\left\{\left(e^{-{\rm i}\fracϕ2}\cos\fracθ2,e^{{\rm i}\fracϕ2}\sin\fracθ2\right):ϕ,θ∈ℝ\right\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

Let $z\in\mathbb C^2$ with $\|z\|=1$. We can easily show that $$\{z\in\mathbb C^2:\|z\|=1\}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}e^{{\rm i}\alpha}\cos\frac\theta2\\e^{{\rm i}\beta}\sin\frac\theta2\end{pmatrix}:\alpha,\beta,\theta\in\mathbb R\right\}\tag1.$$

Now, if $z\in\mathbb C^2$ with $\|z\|=1$ and $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R$ with $$z=\begin{pmatrix}e^{{\rm i}\alpha}\cos\frac\theta2\\e^{{\rm i}\beta}\sin\frac\theta2\end{pmatrix}\tag2,$$ then we may multiply $z$ by $e^{{\rm i}\frac{\alpha+\beta}2}$ to obtain $$e^{{\rm i}\frac{\alpha+\beta}2}z=\begin{pmatrix}e^{-{\rm i}\frac\phi2}\cos\frac\theta2\\e^{{\rm i}\frac\phi2}\sin\frac\theta2\end{pmatrix},\tag3$$ where $\phi:=\alpha-\beta$.

> Have we lost something by the multiplication applied to $z$ or can we conclude that $$\{z\in\mathbb C^2:\|z\|=1\}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}e^{-{\rm i}\frac\phi2}\cos\frac\theta2\\e^{{\rm i}\frac\phi2}\sin\frac\theta2\end{pmatrix}:\phi,\theta\in\mathbb R\right\}\tag4?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All $(z_1, z_2)$ from the set on the right-hand side of $(4)$ satisfy $z_1 \cdot z_2 \in \Bbb R$, which means that this set is *not* identical to the set $\{z\in\mathbb C^2:\|z\|=1\}$.

It should be not too difficult to show that the set on the right-hand side of $(4)$ is *exactly* the set of all $z = (z_1, z_2) \in \Bbb C^2$ with $\Vert z \Vert = 1$ *and* $z_1 z_2 \in \Bbb R$.